# Retrieve only one Int in a XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I am wondering how to use the linq retrieving an XML which looks exactly like this?

```
 <int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">20</int>
```

Should I use the linq? I don't know how to retrieve this number.

This is the code I try to use, I'm stuck after the select. Can someone help me?

```
public void wc_DownloadTopFolder(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieving the Top Folders
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
                int i = from query in xdoc.Descendants("int")
                        select new int
                            {

                            };
            }
```

Comment: You are just interested in that one line of a larger XML file, or that is the entire contents of your xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var number = int.Parse(xdoc.Root.Value);
```

If you are not sure the returned value is a number, you should use this:

```
int number;
if(int.TryParse(xdoc.Root.Value, out number))
{
    // you got a number
}
```

Comment: probably should always use the second, since you can really never guarantee it's a number.

Comment: @Robaticus: If it is always supposed to be a number, I would use the first one, because the case that it is not a number is *exceptional*, so it is fine that an Exception is thrown.

Comment: I agree that it is an exceptional situation, and would certainly consider wrapping it in an exception handler. The only caveat is that he's on an end-user device, and given the expensive nature of an exception, it may be less disruptive to the user to handle this via the second method.  Ultimately, it probably becomes a matter of preference.